# Rails finding all items in a joins that comply with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have `Venue`, `Review` and `Voucher` models. A Venue `has_many` Reviews, and a Review `has_one` Voucher.

A voucher has a boolean `claimed` field.

I'm trying to build a query to select all `claimed: true` Vouchers that are before a certain date, and to return the length of that query.

So far I've tried a few varieties of the following query:

```rb
# @venue is an instance of a Venue
@venue.reviews.joins(:voucher)
    .where(vouchers: { claimed: true })
    .where("created_at < ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week - 7)
    .length
```

However I just get a vague `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error, with my `.length` being highlighted. When I try the above query without the `.length` in the console, I get a `<Review::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation>`

Comment: What do you mean by "return the length of that query"? Do you try to get the count of records? If so, replace `length` by `count`

Comment: @Benj I've also tried substituting `length` for `count`, but I get the same `StatementInvalid` error

Comment: Whats the actual error message here? And please provide an actual reproducable example of you models which will let us actually start whittling down the potential causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the count of vouchers with claimed true and the right timestamp you can just do:

```
Voucher.where(vouchers: { claimed: true })
       .where("created_at < ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week - 7)
       .length
```

Now if you want that for a specific venue, you still want to start the query with `voucher` and then join the venue table onto it:

```
Voucher.joins(review: :venue)
       .where(venue_id: @venue.id)
       .where(vouchers: { claimed: true })
       .where("created_at < ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week - 7)
       .length
```

You might need to play around a bit with `.joins(review: :venue)` you can find more information here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: A more objective comment would have done it, Max. I wrote this answer because I didn't know better (or it was too early in the day). Happy to learn from you once you provide an answer!